# Accessing database within Hasura Action Handler

Tags: database, hasura

I would like to be able to access data from the database within an Action Handler in Hasura. Is the best approach:

- to make a GraphQL query to the API exposed by Hasura; or
- use a client, like Prisma, to read from the db directly?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there is a best approach. Personally, I use the API exposed by Hasura in action handlers. I've chosen to do this because:

- I like the API exposed by Hasura.
- I like the access controls that Hasura layers over top of the DB (although you could just use the admin account, too).
- The API can be used to generate TypeScript types, which I use in the action handler. This means that I can confidently change the database schema or Hasura API and then see where my other code fails.

I have thought many times about your question though, because there is something a little odd about calling back into Hasura to handle a Hasura action. But the reasons mentioned above are substantial gains in my opinion, so I've stuck with this approach.

Comment: Great response, thank you. I totally agree, especially in regards to the codegen feature to be able to properly type out the handler. Cheers :-)

Comment: Hey thank you that is great to hear. It's always nice to see other people have the same questions and concerns.